# How to find sum of neighbor elements in a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, matrix

I am trying to find the sum of neighbors around an element in a matrix and wrote few functions to convert a boolean matrix to 1s and 0s and finding the neighbors. But I'm not sure why it is throwing the following error

```
matrix=[[True,False,False],[False,True,False],[False,False,False]]
def minesweeper(matrix):
    matrix=[[1 if j==True else 0 for j in i] for i in matrix]
    bin_mt = matrix.copy()
    print(bin_mt)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
            matrix[i][j]=get_neighbors(i,j,matrix, bin_mt)
            print('matrix: '+str(matrix))
            print('bin_mt: '+str(bin_mt))

    print(matrix)
    return matrix

def get_neighbors(a, b, matrix, bin_mt):
    sum=0
    if bin_mt[a][b]==1:
        return 1
    else:
        for i in find_neighbor_indices(matrix,a,b):
            print(bin_mt[i[0]][i[1]], end=' ')
            sum=sum+bin_mt[i[0]][i[1]]
        print('--')
        return sum

def find_neighbor_indices(matrix, i, j, dist=1):
    neighbors = []
    irange = range(max(0,i-dist), min(len(matrix), i+dist+1))
    if len(matrix) > 0:
        jrange = range(max(0, j - dist), min(len(matrix[ 0 ]), j + dist + 1))
    else:
        jrange = []
    for icheck in irange:
        for jcheck in jrange:
            if icheck != i or jcheck != j:
                neighbors.append((icheck, jcheck))
    return neighbors
minesweeper(matrix)
```

PS: I have updated the code. However I created a matrix containing 1's and 0's for comparision and sum of neighbors. But I'm not sure why it is updating the both bin_mat and actual matrix instead of just actual matrix. Could someone help me with that.

Comment: You are passing `i ([True, False, False])` to `get_neighbors` as `a` and then passing `a ([True, False, False])` to  `find_neighbor_indices` as `i`, therefore `i` is a list

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code - there is no such a line in it.

Comment: [Using convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html), you can do this in one loc

Comment: @soon  I've updated the code. However, I am not getting the expected output. Please help me with this.

Comment: Please learn how to use debugger

Comment: I did. But unable to figure out the issue. I made the assignment to actual matrix itself. But it is updating both matrices.

Answer (score 0):

No worries. I figured it out. The issue was binary matrix is a shallow copy of actual matrix. Whatever the changes I was making in actual matrix were getting updated in binary matrix. I needed a deep copy instead of shallow.
Solved it using below code.

```
import copy
bin_mt = copy.deepcopy(matrix)
```

instead of

```
bin_mt = matrix.copy()
```